# Writing to a CSV file using Python and adding data

Tags: python, csv

I have a python script that tell me what 'period' it is (for school) which then outputs into a csv file:

```
import datetime
import csv

format = "%H%M"
today = datetime.datetime.today()
s = today.strftime(format)
period = 0

ofile = open('Period.csv', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')

if s > "0845" < "0945":
 period = 1
if s >= "0945" < "1120":
 period = 2
if s >= "1120" < "1220":
 period = 3
if s >= "1220" < "1335":
 period = 4 
if s >= "1335" < "1430":
 period = 5

print
print s
print period

writer.writerow([period])
ofile.close()
```

I have another python script that grabs a student's name once they swipe their student card through a magnetic card reader and then outputs that into a CSV file.

What I want to happen is when they swipe their card their name gets imported into the CSV then the period gets imported next to it (ex. `john,4`). Then the next student will swipe their card and their name and period will be placed under the last students

```
 John,4
 Marcus,4
```

But every time a card it swiped the csv file gets erased and then the current students name is the only one left in there.

```
 import csv
 import datetime

 ## EQ ID

 eqid = "john" ## Output from magnetic card reader


 ## CSV writer

 ofile = open('attendance.csv', "wb")
 writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
 writer.writerow([eqid])
 ofile.close()
```

This is just a temp mock up the final code will have both codes in it.

TL;DR - how do I have python add data to a CSV file instead of just rewriting the whole file?

Comment: Similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file

Comment: open the csv in `a+` mode

Comment: *Aside*: `if s > "0845" < "0945":` doesn't do what you think it does. Perhaps you meant `if "0845" < s < "0945":`.

Comment: @Robᵩ It seems to work when I have been testing it. what is the difference between having 's' at the start or 's' in the middle??

Comment: Did you read the docs for [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)?  You should open fit appending.

Comment: @Sirsyorrz: `s > "0845" < "0945"` firsts compares `s` with `"0845"`, then compares `"0845"` with `"0945"`. The latter comparison will always be trrue. Test it yourself: `s = "1100"; print(s > "0845" < "0945")`

Comment: @Robᵩ ah yes, thank you. I will have to use "0845" > s < "0945": though as I want s to be greater then the start time and less then the finish time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But every time a card it swiped the csv file gets erased and then the current students name is the only one left in there.

This is because you are writing (`"wb"`) the file every time the card is swiped, which means a new file is created (an existing file with the same name will be erased). So You should use `"ab"` mode which is appending values in existing file.
So the line

```
ofile = open('attendance.csv', "wb")
```

should be changed to

```
ofile = open('attendance.csv', "ab")
```

Now everytime card is swiped the values will be appended.

you can check File Operations at [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files](http://Python%20official%20Docs)